# Plot many data sets (from csv) on single graph

Tags: r, ggplot2

Following this example:

http://wiki.stdout.org/rcookbook/Graphs/Multiple%20graphs%20on%20one%20page%20(ggplot2)/

See the graph titled "Fitted growth curve per diet", I want to do the same thing but with a set of data that is in a CSV file such as (values are in µs, except for column "N"):

```
$ head RandomArray25PercentDup.csv 
N   SystemSort  QuickSort   RandomizedQuickSort TopDownMergeSort    BottomUpMergeSort   SelectionSort   InsertionSort   BubbleSort  
4   0   1   0   1   0   1   0   0   
5   0   0   0   1   1   0   1   0   
6   0   0   0   1   1   0   0   0   
7   0   0   0   0   1   0   0   0   
8   0   0   1   0   1   0   1   1   

...
```

I've tried this so far:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(reshape2)

data <- read.table("RandomArray25PercentDup.csv",
                   sep="\t",
                   header=TRUE)
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars = 1)

ggplot(data.m, aes(data, value, colour=variable)) +
    geom_point(alpha=.3) +
    geom_smooth(alpha=.2, size=1) +
    ggtitle("Random array with ~25% duplicate values")
```

My background in R is very limited, and I'm trying to learn using various ressources.

I have about 800'000 rows worth of data, with 20 repetitions in the measurement of each N (the reason why I want to see the scatter in transparent with a fitting curve for each algorithm).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replacing this

```
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars = 1)
```

with

```
data.m <- melt(data, id.vars = "N")
```

and then

```
ggplot(data.m, aes(data, value, colour=variable)) +
    geom_point(alpha=.3) +
    geom_smooth(alpha=.2, size=1) +
    ggtitle("Random array with ~25% duplicate values")
```

with

```
ggplot(data.m, aes(N, value, colour=variable)) +
    geom_point(alpha=.3) +
    geom_smooth(alpha=.2, size=1) +
    ggtitle("Random array with ~25% duplicate values")
```

should do the trick. First replacement isn't really necessary, but it's always preferable to use variable names in case the order of the columns change. The first argument in `aes` is mapped to the x-axis. `data` is not a column so it can't be mapped.